# How are optimal weights computed in best-Worst Multi-criteria Decision Making Method (Step 5 of BWM)? Can someone explain it with an example?

Tags: decision-problem, social-networks

Title: Best-worst multi-criteria decision-making method
Author:Jafar Rezaei, Pub: Omega 53 (2015) 49-57 [BWMCD](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305048314001480)

From this [example](http://bestworstmethod.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Best-Worst-Method-BWM-2017-w.pdf) How are optimal weights (W1*, W2* etc) computed on Page:22 ?
what are the values of WB, Wj, aBj, WW, ajW  for W1 and W2 such that optimal weight of W1* = [0.1579, 0.2469] and W2* = [0.4286, 4932].

PS: Not much experience in Linear Programming.

Comment: The link to the paper you give is behind a paywall and therefore may not be accessible to all visitors of this site. Could you put the relevant information from that link (in particular, equation 5) to this post, so that it is becomes more accessible?

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide a full citation (paper title, authors, where published), so that the question still makes sense even if the link stops working, and so that others with a similar question about the paper can find this page via web search?  And if you can find a freely available PDF of the paper, please add a link to that.  Otherwise, please edit the question to include/quote all relevant context so that the question is understandable for people who can't access that link.  Thank you!

Comment: Updated necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal weights are the solution to the optimisation problem given by model (2), i.e. the optimisation problem:

> $ \min \xi$
>
> s.t.
>
> $|\frac{w_B}{w_j}-a_{B_j}|\leq \xi$, for all $j$
>
> $|\frac{w_j}{w_W}-a_{jW}|\leq \xi$, for all $j$
>
> $\sum_j w_j=1$
>
> $w_j\geq0$, for all $j$

The parameters $a_{B_j}$ and $a_{jW}$ are defined in the slides on pages 10 and 11. From this, your can work out the values in the particular example.

Solving the above problem may be difficult, which is why model (5), a linear approximation of model (2) is suggested.

> $ \min \xi^L$
>
> s.t.
>
> $w_B-a_{B_j}w_j\leq \xi^L$, for all $j$
>
> $-(w_B-a_{B_j}w_j)\leq \xi^L$, for all $j$
>
> $w_j-a_{jW}w_W\leq \xi^L$, for all $j$
>
> $-(w_j-a_{jW}w_W)\leq \xi^L$, for all $j$
>
> $\sum_j w_j=1$
>
> $w_j\geq0$, for all $j$

(This is essentially model (5) from the slides, but with the absolute value inequality split over 2 inequalities)

As the variables are the values $\xi^L$ and $w_j$, the goal function and all constraints are linear, so this is a linear optimisation problem (aka a linear program). This means that we can use the technique of [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to find a solution to this problem, which would give the required values.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Actually I am trying to recompute the values from the example from start and I am not able to figure out what value does WB, Wj, WW hold w.r.t given example. Can you explain that for W1 ?

Comment: The parameters are given on slide 21: $A_B=(2,1,4,3,8)$, $A_W=(4,8,4,2,1)$. As far as I can see, $W_W$, $W_j$ and $W_B$ are all variables in the optimization problem, so I think they form the vector $w^*$.